# Joomla Template with different layouts for different sections of the website

Tags: templates, joomla

I am very new with Joomla, and I have to create a template for joomla 3.0 based on a design given.

I have read a lot of manuals and tutorials about "simple joomla" templates that explain how to organize the directory structure, xml file, index.php and so on.

But I don't see where we can define different layouts for different sections of the website, for example:

1. Layout for the home page
2. Layout for articles listing (on search for example)
3. Layout for the article itself.

I am sure there must be thousands of tutorials regarding that point, bu I simply cannot find it.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the concepts you may be missing is "Template and Layout Overrides".

Components (the elements of Joomla! that create the main section of any given page) control the layout of any of their views.  To change these a template need to create a matching override for the specific view.

A similar process is used for "Modules" the smaller elements of a web page (e.g. side-bar advertising or widgets).

Have a read of these articles:

- [How to override the output from Joomla! Core](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)
- [Understanding Output Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)
- [Converting a template for Joomla! 3](http://docs.joomla.org/Converting_a_template_for_Joomla_3)

You may also want to look at the "[Joomla 3.x Template Overrides Example](http://www.youjoomla.com/joomla-tutorials/joomla-3-template-overrides-example.html)" that You!Joomla created a while back.

Finally given that Joomla! 3.0 is a Short Term Support version (and 3.1 is due any day and so on) you will probably be advised to use the "[Template Overrides in Joomla! 3.0](http://forum.joomla.org/viewforum.php?f=718)" forum for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in Isis you will see an example of using conditions to change he layout, that is how the control panel is so differen than the rest of the admin.  You can either do it all in one file or you can have  separate files